# How to place Lyx macros in all my documents?

Tags: lyx

I figured out how to make macros in Lyx (insert->math->macro) so I'm super excited. But they only seem to apply in the document they are in. How can I include my macros automatically in all documents that I use?

Comment: In LaTeX macros are local to the document.  However, you can put them in a separate file inserted via `\input`, or a `.sty` file called via `\usepackage`

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way. One LyX user says he solved it, as noted here: https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg186365.html. He states "(I solved this (kind of) with an include-file full of math macros.)" You might want to ask that user exactly how he did it.

Comment: Duplicated by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356811/macro-file-in-lyx-importing-macro-files